# Time Capsule suddenly won't Time Machine, get error about format

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

My several-year-old Time Capsule suddenly failed to back up, throwing up this message:

```
The backup disk is not in Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format, which is required.
```

It was last night when it successfully backed up at 8:36!

I am used to error messages not really meaning what they say, so before I reformat, any other suggestions?

Comment: Go to Disk Utility and try running First Aid.

Comment: How do I get the drive visible in Disk Utility?

Comment: You have to mount it first.

Comment: Go to Terminal and type ```diskutil list```. Once you find the device that you want note down the diskIdentififer (), type ```diskutil repairVolume diskIdentifier```. Then, the repair process is complete. This is an alternative to Disk Utility First Aid if it doesn't work.

Comment: It does not appear in that list either. Dead drive?

Comment: Try using it on another computer. If it doesn't work even after that, then it might be dead.

Comment: If you don't need any previous backups, you can erase the drive and redo Time Machine. You can also use Safe Boot to isolate issues with your Mac. I would recommend uninstalling third party anitviruses unless they are necessary.

Comment: Reboot fixed it *sigh*

Comment: Lol ok Did you try Safe Boot

Comment: Reboot of the TC, apparently that does a permissions fix.

Comment: Would need to find the source, but from what I recall, there can be periodic issues when the volume (Time Capsule or not) Time Machine uses isn't directly connected to the Mac. Usually, in my experience, a reboot is the best solution.

Comment: My backup drive is a WDMyCloud NAS drive and I was getting the same error.  Last successful backup was at 4:13am. In my case, a reboot of the WDMyCloud also resolved the issue. The backup is "Backing up" currently, whereas before, I kept getting the error immediately after the "preparing" stage.